# What Summer Does the “Summer of Xy Year” Refer To?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, phrase-meaning

If someone says "the summer of senior year", are they referring to the summer before senior year, where the student was a rising senior, or are they referring to the summer after graduation, when the student was a rising freshmen?

Comment: How is someone a freshman _after_ graduation?

Comment: Rising freshmen, maybe going into college.

Comment: @nnnnnn Graduating high school, to become a college freshman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience this means the summer *before* one's senior year, but as a sanity-check, I searched Google Books for "the summer of my senior year" and looked at the first three hits.

In two of them, the context shows that it means "the summer before my senior year", as I'd expected:

- "I decided to go to Mexico the summer of my senior year. […] Then I had to scramble to find money for that senior year." [[link](https://books.google.com/books?id=xT7nAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA30)]
- "In the summer of my senior year, we were married and moved into the dorm for married students. ¶ With great difficulty, I got through my last year at seminary, but […]" [[link](https://books.google.com/books?id=-gmTDAAAQBAJ&pg=PT60)]

but in one, the context suggests that it means "the summer at the end of my senior year":

- "It was the summer of my senior year, and it was time to return to Rochester. Graduation was around the corner, and since the start of spring break, I was stuck in Texas finishing the second semester of my senior year online. […] It was the last time I would be around my friends before we set off for college to never return quite the same as when we left." [[link](https://books.google.com/books?id=OkZKEAAAQBAJ&pg=PT57)]

(though I find that passage confusing enough that I can't be 100% sure).

---

Personally I will continue to interpret "the summer of my senior year" as meaning "the summer before my senior year" except when context clearly suggests otherwise.